# Bound for $|\log(1 - x) + x|$.

Tags: calculus, analysis

I am having trouble proving the following:

Deduce that for $0 < x < 1$ we have
$$|\log(1 - x) + x| < cx^2$$
for some constant $c$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: For $x \in (0,1)$, $x-1$ is negative. Did you mean $\log(1-x)$?

Comment: @Marvis Yes, I did. Change has been made.

Comment: This isn't true, since as $x\to1$ the LHS $\to\infty$ whilst the RHS $\to c$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use the power series for $\ln(1-x)$, which is
$$-\left(x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots\right).$$
Adding $x$ and taking absolute values, we get
$$x^2\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x}{3}+\frac{x^2}{4}+\cdots\right).$$
There is no universal $c$ that will work, since the "tail" $\frac{x}{3}+\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{x^3}{5}+\cdots$ can be made arbitrarily large by taking $x$ close enough to $1$.

**Remark:** The non-existence of $c$ was obvious to begin with, since $-\log(1-x)$ blows up.  But it is useful if we know a little more about $x$. If we know, for example, that $x\lt \frac{9}{10}$, we can use the geometric series $\frac{x}{3}+\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{x^3}{5}+\cdots$ to bound the tail. But there is no "universal" $c$.